# Using Parse Method with Generic Type?

Tags: c#, parsing, generics, c#-4.0

Straight to the code:

```
class ArithmeticExpressionParser<T> : Parser
{
    T num1, num2;

    /* ......... */

    void ParseNumber()
    {
        string temp = String.Empty;

        while (char.IsDigit(PeekNextToken()))
        {
            GetNextToken();
            temp += Token;
        }

        num1 = T.Parse(temp);  // <<< the problem
    }
```

Basically, if I was using an `int` or `double` I would have just use `int.Parse` etc. I've tried casting `num1 = (T)temp;` , which didn't work. How can I do this without having to write a custom `string` to `T` function?

Comment: It feels like you want an `IParsable` but `IConvertible` is more inclusive (and exists)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
class ArithmeticExpressionParser<T> : Parser where T : IConvertible
{
    T num1, num2;

    /* ......... */

    void ParseNumber()
    {
        string temp = String.Empty;

        while (char.IsDigit(PeekNextToken()))
        {
            GetNextToken();
            temp += Token;
        }

        //num1 = T.Parse(temp);  // <<< the problem
        num1 = (T)Convert.ChangeType( temp, typeof( T ) );
    }
}
```

This assumes that all the types you are converting implement `IConvertible`, which will allow you to place a generic constraint on your parser class. If not all types are convertible, you will need to switch conversion methods based on the type (messy).

If necessary, you can also implement IConvertible on your own types. There are many methods to implement, but if you are dealing with primitive values it usually doesn't take too long to implement.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx

Comment: By using Convert.ChangeType, you have boxing when T is a value type.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Convert.ChangeType` for converting. The following code should work with all simple types and

```
    public static T Parse<T>(this string source)
    {            
        if (typeof(T).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Enum)))
        {
            return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), source, true);
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(source, typeof(T));

        return default(T);
    }
```

Comment: Convert.ChangeType causes boxing, however, which could be avoided using a group of method overloads.

Comment: @phoog - method overloads don't work in this case, because the difference in type is on the return type, not the parameter type - the parameter is always string, so overloading is not applicable.

Comment: @DaveRael good point, I used the wrong word.  What I meant to indicate was a group of methods that include the name of the type in the method name, as in `X.ParseDouble` and `X.ParseByte`, which is no more typing than `X.Parse<double>` and `X.Parse<byte>`.